# Explanation needed scala fixedpoint from coursera

Tags: scala, functional-programming, square-root, coursera-api

I was going through videos of Functional Programming in Scala taught in coursera. I came across these code

```
def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double) = (x + f(x)) / 2
```

and its implementation as

```
  def sqrt(x: Double): Double = fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => y / x))(1)
```

but couldn't use it in the form

```
  averageDamp(x => x)
```

It says that argument is missing. Isn't the argument missing in above case as well. Somebody help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Partial application of multiple parameter list methods is only possible (a) explicitly (like `averageDamp(x => x) _`) or (b) implicitly in a functional context (like `val f: Double => Double = averageDamp(x => x)`). My guess is that `fixedPoint` requires `Double => Double`, so we have option (b)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword for this is `currying`. When `averageDamp` defined as above, `averageDamp` will expect two parameters. When you write it with only first paramater it will return a functional (closure) which takes another argument. Thats why it says `argument is missing` when you call it like `averageDamp(x => x)`. You just calling a function without parameter which expects one. To actually evaluate the value you should call it like `averageDamp(some_function)(double_value)`.

Checkout this: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala

Comment: `When you call it with first parameter it will return a function (closure)` this part is wrong. You can't call it with only first parameter (technically first  **parameter list** here), unless you are in a functional context and Scala knows you expect a function, and what is missing is a complete parameter list.

Comment: You are right calling is not the correct verb here.

Comment: I was calculating the square root. Still cannot use as: averageDamp(y => x/y)(1)